# Autorun PHP method

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that needs to perform a method once a day. However, how to do this in PHPOO?

P.S: In POOP, I used crontab or Fcron to program a URL to be executed at a certain time. In that script, I justed put the necessary modifications.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I fail to see how it would be any different when doing POOP instead of "structure PHP"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cronjob anyway because PHP only triggers scripts when a http-request or xmlhttprequest comes in which is mostly sent by a browser and sometims by a service or program.

OOP doesnt help you here either and has nothing to do with the way "how code is executed" its just a smart design pattern to make your code reusable, more readable, extendable and alot of more advantages...